# Django sometimes fetching datetimes in native form from PostgreSQL even though USE_TZ = True

Tags: django, postgresql, datetime, timezone, django-registration

I'm using Django 1.4 and PostgreSQL.

In settings.py I have:

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Creation of dates always makes offset-aware timezones:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 1, 7, 48, 12, 636318, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Models from my own app return timezone aware dates.

```
>>> from fundedbyme.campaign.models import *
>>> e = EquityCampaign.objects.all()[0].created
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 19, 11, 29, 57, 844642, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

From some other third party apps I return offset aware dates.

```
>>> from paypaladaptive.models import Payment
>>> Payment.objects.all()[0].created_date
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 14, 11, 58, 47, 713878, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

However the User model does not have a timezone aware date.

```
>>> u = User.objects.all()[0]
>>> u.date_joined
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 13, 16, 20, 37, 709550)
```

Why would only the django user model not return offset aware datetimes? This is causing me a serious bug when I use django-registration. In the line linked to below, a native and aware date get compared.

https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/models.py?at=default#cl-218 it

I've looked in the auth_user table in postgres and the date_joined field is a "timestamp with time zone" field.

Why would I get native dates returned only on the User model?